# ActionMailer 3 error - undefined method `encode!' for "Welcome":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I'm getting this error while sending mail to the registered user in rails 3:

`undefined method 'encode!' for "Welcome":String`

I have the following code

```
 @content = content
 mail(:to => content[:email], :subject => "test")
```

If there is a subject then above error message displaying, if I remove the subject content

```
@content = content
mail(:to => content[:email], :subject => "") no error message sending with out subject
```

I'm using:

- Rails version 3.0.1
- action mailer 3.0.1

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Answer (score 1):

mail gem checks for Encoded global constant. If its defined by any gem or your code then it calls encode! on the mail object. Here is this call from UnstructuredField mail gem class:

```
def encode(value)
  value.encode!(charset) if defined?(Encoding) && charset
  (value.not_ascii_only? ? [value].pack("M").gsub("=\n", '') : value).gsub("\r", "=0D").gsub("\n", "=0A")
end
```

For me it was mail subject, a String, so I monkey patched String:

```
class String
  def encode!(value)
   #Do any encoding or simply return it
   value
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ruby version 1.9
I got this error while using devise with rails 3.0.3 and ruby 1.8.7.
I migrated to ruby 1.9 and it worked like a charm.